# Authentication failure connecting to node - Could not authenticate error on Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I have a node in `Rundeck 4.10 community version with ubuntu 22` where I am trying to make SSH from Rundeck. Its giving authentication error. The node is as follows

```
<node name="node-name" description="node-description" tags="reg"
        hostname="node-name" username="ubuntu"
        osFamily="unix" osName="Ubuntu"> 
</node>
```

My SSH key is in this path on the server: `/home/ubuntu/rundeck/privatekey.pem`

And on Rundeck storage, it is in this path: `keys/project/project_name/privatekey`

This target node is also running on Ubuntu 22. But I have other nodes which are running on Ubuntu 18 and I am able to execute jobs from Rundeck on these nodes with this existing SSH key configuration except on the node with Ubuntu 22. My other nodes are working without mentioning the ssh-key-storage-path name in resources file. I added ssh-key-storage-path attribute also in the resources.xml file an tried running the job from Rundeck.

I tried connecting to this ubuntu 22 target server from Rundeck shell and it is working fine but from Rundeck GUI, its giving authentication error.
Below is the error in detail:

```
   Authentication failure connecting to node: "node-name". Could not authenticate.
Failed dispatching to node node-name: [jsch-scp] Failed copying the file: Authentication failure connecting to node: "node-name". Could not authenticate.
Execution failed: in project project-name: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [node-name: AuthenticationFailure: [jsch-scp] Failed copying the file: Authentication failure connecting to node: "node-name". Could not authenticate.]}, Node failures: {node-name=[AuthenticationFailure: [jsch-scp] Failed copying the file: Authentication failure connecting to node: "node-name". Could not authenticate.]}, status: failed]
```

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some modern linux distrubutions the default SSH Node Executor needs some changes to work with the default Rundeck SSH node executor.

Option 1: Use the SSHJ node executor instead of the "SSH" default node executor. To do so, go to the Project > Project Settings (left menu) > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor/File Copier (tabs) and select SSHJ (on both tabs).

Option 2: In your remote SSH server, edit the `sshd_config` file and add this:

`PublickeyAcceptedKeysTypes +ssh-rsa`

Then, restart the SSH service.

Comment: thank you. Its working now. But I did not modify `sshd_config` file and I modified only rundeck configurations. 
I have a doubt. I have one more `Rundeck version 2.6.9`. I don't find SSHJ Option over there. How can I make this target node executable from Older version of Rundeck too?

Comment: when I modify `sshd_config` file, it gave below error. 
`Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xeu ssh.service" for details.`
So did not change in `sshd_config` file.

Comment: That error is due some misconfiguration on the sshd_config file, follow the command suggested on the error message to solve it. A good advice is to check the ssh service status after any change. Take a look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725731

Comment: How can I make it work on older version of `Rundeck 2.6.9`?

Comment: The option 2 sounds good, in that way the remote node can "understand" the default rundeck model source keys. A good advice is to upgrade that old instance, Rundeck 2.6.9 is too old and newer versions contains a lot of new features and problems fixed.

Comment: I got new issue now with this setting `Project > Project Settings (left menu) > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor/File Copier (tabs) and select SSHJ (on both tabs)` When I execute rundeck jobs for remote nodes where it will execute scripts to launch one app, applications are not coming up and app is going off immediately after starting. Do I need enable `keepaliveinterval` option set so that ssh connection doesn't go off in backend? Do you have any idea about this?